# How to display UL list vertical?

Tags: php, html, css

I have `ul` list with `li` sorted by name. How I can display these elements vertically?
I mean structure:

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

Now It works as:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

This issue is not actual and may be deleted

Comment: Use the sort code. Or try, `array.transpose()`.

Comment: PHP doesn't have `ul` lists or `li`, those are HTML.... how are you using PHP to generate that HTML? What is the structure you're using in PHP? Is it an array?

Comment: You are very trivially about PHP and HTML :) It is array if talk about PHP with `key => value`: `$arr = array("0" => array("name" => "1"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be in HTML-CSS.

- Your `<li>` should have a css style of `diplay: inline;` or `float: left;` or `float: right;` to display it beside each other.
- Your `<ul>` tag should have css style of `display: block;` so that each `<ul>` is displayed line by line.

Comment: Now I have the same how you wrote, it does not work